# Como puedo hacer una iteracion para encontrar el error de una raiz? c++

Tags: c++

Necesito encontrar la raíz de un numero real (El error para ser exactos) sé que la formula es:

PrimerAproximacion = x/2

Aproximacion = 1/2 (Aproximacion anterior + x/AproximacionAnterior)

Y  que el error de cada iteración es:
Error = |AproximacionActual - AproximacionAnterior|

Lo que no puedo hacer es usar algún ciclo para repetir todo el proceso

```
        std::cout << "Valor del n" << char(163) << "mero: ";    //Impresión para la solicitud para sacar la raíz del numero dado
        std::cin >> numeroRaiz;                                 //Lectura del número dado
   
        //Validación de entrada para numeroRaiz
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n');
        
        while (numeroRaiz <= 0) {
            std::cout << "Vuelve a introducir un numero: ";
            std::cin >> numeroRaiz;
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n');
        }

    std::cout << "Tolerancia para el Error: ";              //Impresión para la solicitud del Error de la raíz
    std::cin >> Tolerancia;                                      //Lectura del Error dado

    //Validación de entrada de ERROR
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n');
    while (Tolerancia <= 0) {
        std::cout << "Vuelve a introducir un numero: ";
        std::cin >> Tolerancia;
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n');
```

¿Cómo puedo usar un ciclo para repetir todo el proceso hasta que el Error sea igual o mayor que la tolerancia?

Comment: Quizá quieran que uses recursión.

Answer (score 0):

Ok lo resolví con un do while de esta forma:

```
            std::cout << "Valor del n" << char(163) << "mero: ";    //Impresión para la solicitud para sacar la raíz del numero dado
        std::cin >> numeroRaiz;                                 //Lectura del número dado
   
        //Validación de entrada para numeroRaiz
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n');
        
        while (numeroRaiz <= 0) {
            std::cout << "Vuelve a introducir un numero: ";
            std::cin >> numeroRaiz;
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n');
        }

    std::cout << "Tolerancia para el Error: ";              //Impresión para la solicitud del Error de la raíz
    std::cin >> Tolerancia;                                      //Lectura del Error dado

    //Validación de entrada de ERROR
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n');
    while (Tolerancia <= 0) {
        std::cout << "Vuelve a introducir un numero: ";
        std::cin >> Tolerancia;
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n');
    }
    //Primera operación para la encontrar raíz
    Operacion = numeroRaiz / 2;
    
    //Inicio de ciclo para encontrar la raiz y el error
    do {
        aproxActual = 0.5 * (Operacion + (numeroRaiz / Operacion));

        Error = abs(aproxActual - Operacion);
        Operacion = aproxActual;

        
        std::cout << aproxActual << std::endl;
        std::cout << Error << std::endl;
        if (Error <= Tolerancia) break;

    } while(true);
```

Por si alguien algún día se ofrece, ahí esta la aproximación de una raíz c++

Comment: Hola! En la última parte del `do-while` yo pondría la negación de la condición del `if` en el `while`, en lugar de `while(true)`